# STM32 bootloader protocol

Tags: stm32, bootloader, hex-file

I am attempting to update the application code on an STM32 chip programatically from another chip.  I have an Intel format hex file generated from the build process and I would like to use the bootloader shipped with the STM32 chip for writing the updated application following [AN3155](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/51/5f/03/1e/bd/9b/45/be/CD00264342.pdf/files/CD00264342.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00264342.pdf).  My question regards the format of the actual data in the `Write Memory Command` - should this data be shipped as hex? i.e. when quoting the length - 16 bytes would be shipped as a 32-byte ascii representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own link specifies this as a binary protocol:

```
The host sends the bytes to the STM32 as follows:
Byte 1: 0x31
Byte 2: 0xCE
Wait for ACK
Byte 3 to byte 6:Start address (byte 3: MSB, byte 6: LSB)
Byte 7: Checksum: XOR (byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6)
Wait for ACK
Byte 8: Number of bytes to be received (0 < N ≤ 255)
N +1 data bytes:(Max 256 bytes)
Checksum byte:XOR (N, N+1 data bytes)
```

The *contents* of the binary packet are similar to a line in a hex file (or an amalgamation of several contiguous ones) but this is binary, not an ASCII-hex representation.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the response, Chris.  So, all of the bytes written as a binary string then, i.e. (from above) Byte 1 = 1, Byte 2 = Î...etc etc?

Comment: The bytes are defined in the document you linked you just create those packets and send them.